# Send data from android to mysql using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, http

I have a some text on an android client, I want to send it to the database(MySQL). How do I do this.Please help me with this. I tried using php and Mysql. Is the query in Php right??

Here is what I have tried
**Insert.java**

```
public class Insert extends ListActivity {
String[] ct_name = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InputStream is = null;
    // http post
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();       
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c_name","KL"));
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/city1.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

I am not sure about the php file but here goes

**city1.php**

```
<?php
   $hostname_localhost ="localhost";
   $database_localhost ="mydatabase";
   $username_localhost ="root";
   $password_localhost ="";

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost) 
    or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

   mysql_select_db($database_localhost);
   $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO CITY (CITY_NAME)VALUES('".$_REQUEST['c_name']."')");
   //for updation
   //$sql=update CITY set CITY_NAME='".$_REQUEST['c_name']."' where CITY_ID=22
   $r=mysql_query($sql);
   if(!$r)
   echo "Error in query: ".mysql_error();
   mysql_close();
?>
```

**MYSQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `mydatabase`.`city` (
`CITY_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`CITY_NAME` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you try these things at the moment? Do you get error messages at all?

Comment: @halfer I don't get any error message as such. But when I check my database the data "KL" is not added into the table

Comment: OK, debugging time then. Have you checked that $_REQUEST is populated with value(s) from your sender?

Comment: (You should bear in mind that your code as it stands permits SQL injection - so don't run this on the internet unless you don't mind people dropping your database for you!)

Comment: No this is just for learning @halfer :) Can u suggest a good tutorial to overcome SQL Injection. It would be great

Comment: Yes In the database its populating more values than required.
Can I replace  $_REQUEST with something else??

Comment: For SQL injection, just google 'sql injection php' - there will be loads of articles.

Comment: Your city1.php code as it stands will only insert one column, one row. Are you sure it is only being called once? Have a look in your web server logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd change this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO CITY (CITY_NAME)VALUES('".$_REQUEST['c_name']."')");
```

to

```
$c_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['c_name']);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO CITY (CITY_NAME) VALUES('".$c_name."')");
```

Otherwise, you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!

**EDIT:**

I'm assuming this line:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT ...
```

should be

```
$sql="INSERT ...
```

?

Otherwise this line makes no sense:

```
$r=mysql_query($sql);
```

Also, is there any output indicating an error when accessing http://10.0.2.2/city1.php?c_name=Foobar from your browser?

@JLevett Even though unrelated to the problem at hand, that vuln was the first thing that caught my eye, so I wanted to point that out quickly, before dealing with the problem itself.

Comment: Although SQL injection is a problem it's not a solution to this question.

Comment: @caspase - Thank you so much. But In the database its populating more values than require. Why is that happening?

Comment: Most mysql/php related questions are followed up by an answer involving inject. It would of been better suited as a comment like the others. However your updated answer makes sense as the OP is calling mysql_query twice.

Comment: @JLevett Sorry, didn't have the "Comment everywhere" privilege until now ;)

Comment: @JLevett - The value is getting inserted but its repeating 4 times. Why is that happening??